# how to dynamically create a file based on form submitted data

Tags: php, forms, file, dynamic

I have been searching for hours on how to do this, and am asking for help on what I would like to do.

I would like to **dynamically create** a file, based on form submitted data using radio buttons as the variable.

**For example:**

```
if ($_POST['radio_button_selection'] == "percussion") {

file_put_contents("dynamic_filename.txt", $_POST['radio_button_selection']);

echo "Dynamic filename created";

}
```

---

**I tried:**

```
if ($_POST['radio_button_selection'] == "percussion") {

file_put_contents("({$_POST['percussion']})", $_POST['radio_button_selection']);

echo "Percussion file created.";

}
```

But this is not working.

I know I have a missing piece of code to give it the extension, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**(EDIT)**
Do I need to modify this with PHP code in order to create the file "percussion" as well as write data in the file of the same name?

```
<input type="radio" value="percussion" name="musictype">Percussion
```

For example, create the file "percussion.txt" with the word "percussion" in the file.

The code below works and creates the file "percussion.txt" and writes the word "percussion" in the file, but I need the file to be created dynamically while writing to it at the same time.

```
file_put_contents("percussion.txt", $_POST['musictype'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Does the file you are putting to exist? Does the directory you are writing to have write permissions?

Comment: What other fields are on the form?  What do you want to name the file?

Comment: no, the file will need to be newly created J.Money

Comment: The file needs to be named as per radio button selected Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bsdnoobz just has it switched.

```
file_put_contents($_POST['radio_button_selection'].'.txt', $_POST['percussion']);
```

Make sure the folder you are writing to has write permission.

Comment: If you want the contents of the file to be precussion also just use: `file_put_contents($_POST['radio_button_selection'].'.txt', $_POST['radio_button_selection']);`

Comment: Thanks it created the file but it didn't write the value of "percussion" in the file as it did before when I passed the value directly to it. For example, is the value is "percussion" and it creates the file of the same name, how can I also have it write its content?

Comment: Try: `file_put_contents($_POST['musictype']."txt",$_POST['musictype']);` Now that the file is created and it was blank make sure you have the permission to edit that file. Try deleting the file and doing it again. If it works then you probably don't have edit permission for some reason. Also if you want to append like you put in your most recent post just add the append option to file_put_contents.

Comment: It worked to a certain extent, created the file and wrote the word "percussion" in it, but it named the file "percussiontxt" with no DOT between percussion and txt.

Comment: Sorry typo: `file_put_contents($_POST['musictype'].".txt",$_POST['musictype']);`

Comment: Not a problem :) Worked beautifully! Thank you very much, I appreciate it, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file_put_contents($_POST['percussion'].'.txt', $_POST['radio_button_selection']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. It only created a file called .txt without the word "percussion" in front of it.

Comment: Check if the variable is empty with `var_dump($_POST['percussion'])`.

Comment: got this back Percussion file created.NULL